# How to read keyboard inputs in Octave while running loop?

Tags: input, octave

Problem:

I'm running a script that includes an infinite loop and I would like to exit from this loop with user input. I don't want to use the standard "input" function because that pauses the execution of the loop while it waits for the user inputs. I want that the program keeps looping all the time (until some certain keyboard input is given). I don't want to exit from the loop with ctrl+c either because then the program shut down procedures that are located after the loop, are not executed.

Question:

In octave, when something is typed to the command window during execution of a script nothing is shown in the command window until the script has ended. From this it is clear that keyboard inputs that are given during the execution of a script are stored somewhere (is this right?). And now the big guestion is where? And how can I access this data?

I'm running Octave 4.0.0 in Win7

p.s. also other suggestions for stopping the loop are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use kbhit:

```
while (1)
  if (kbhit (1) == 'x')
    break
  endif

  sleep (0.2)
  printf ("Loop is running...\n");
  fflush (stdout);

endwhile
```

Or if you want to exit with ctrl-c and finalize your script use a unwind_protect, unwind_ptrotect_cleanup block

```
unwind_protect
  while (1)
    sleep (0.2)
    printf ("Loop is running...\n");
    fflush (stdout);
  endwhile
unwind_protect_cleanup
  disp ("doing my cleanup");
end_unwind_protect
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! Either of these will solve my problem. I'm going to use the unwind_protect solution since the kbhit based solution behaved a bit inconsistently on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

> In octave, when something is typed to the command window during execution of a script nothing is shown in the command window until the script has ended. From this it is clear that keyboard inputs that are given during the execution of a script are stored somewhere (is this right?). And now the big guestion is where? And how can I access this data?

This is called buffering and is a very common behaviour. The principle is simple. Instead of writing everything as it's ready, your system will keep it on a buffer and only write it when told to do so, or when the buffer is full. Many disks operations work like this, for example, when you copy a few small files into a USB stick (dependent on the mount options). Once the buffer is full, or when you click to eject the USB, stick, the system will then actually perform the write.

If you read the section [Paging Screen Output](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html) of the Octave manual you will see:

> Normally, no output is displayed by the pager until just before Octave is ready to print the top level prompt, or read from the standard input (for example, by using the fscanf or scanf functions). This means that there may be some delay before any output appears on your screen if you have asked Octave to perform a significant amount of work with a single command statement. The function fflush may be used to force output to be sent to the pager (or any other stream) immediately.

Alternatively, you can turn off this buffering with `page_output_immediately()`:

> Query or set the internal variable that controls whether Octave sends output to the pager as soon as it is available.
>
> Otherwise, Octave buffers its output and waits until just before the prompt is printed to flush it to the pager.